# No command window

Tags: windows-7

Using 7 build 7600. Wen I try to open a command window, I just get returned to my previous folder/desktop. If I try to open an elevated window I get to the UAC, answer yes and again am returned. A check in Sys info reveals the command prompt is running but I can't see the window. I can have multiple instances of cmd.exe running but still no window. My video adapter is GeForce 7600 and I have no other known problems at this time.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you ALT+Tab?  Do you see the command window in the preview window?  It could be off the screen or hidden for some reason.